Compilation error while adding two matrices
Dear Mathematica users,
I would like to compile my function and my sample code is as:
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
$CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler,"CompilerInstallation" -> "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin", "CompilerName" -> "gcc.exe"};

c = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];

cf2 = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 0}, {b, _Integer, 0}, {d, _Real, 2}},

Block[

{ahmet = ConstantArray[0, {a, b}]},

Do[
  

 Do[
   

   ahmet[[i, j]] = ahmet[[i, j]] + d[[i, j]];

   , {i, 1, a}
   ];

  , {j, 1, b}
  ];

 ahmet

     ],CompilationTarget -> "C"

            ];

Executing the code does not give an error. However, calling
cf2[2, 2, c]

gives errors as:
CompiledFunction::cfte: Compiled expression {{0.0712815,0},{0,0}} should be a rank 2 tensor of machine-size integers. >>
CompiledFunction::cfexe: Could not complete external evaluation; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
Why does calling the function result in such an error? Could someone help me about this issue? I appreciate for it.
Best wishes,
Ahmet

Change to ahmet = ConstantArray[0., {a, b}] (note the period after 0).

I have solved the problem while adding two matrices and maybe, it can help the others. The problem is matrix c is defined as random real and while assigning it into function, and adding it with ahmet[[i,j]]; matrix ahmet also has to be real  type, however the definition of ConstantArray results in integer matrix. To make ahmet matrix to be a real type, I have written it as:
ahmet=N[ConstantArray[0,{a,b}];

Then it is permitted to add two real type matrices.
